# What did Grubbs mean when he "cautioned against interpreting probabilities too literally when normality of the data is not assured"?

Tags: outliers

In his 1969 paper, Grubbs mentioned that "Until such time as criteria not sensitive to the normality assumption are developed, the experimenter is cautioned against interpreting probabilities too literally when normality of the data is not assured".

Say I have n data points and I want to test for outliers using the Grubbs' test in that data. I'm told I need to remove the suspected outlier to test the normality of the data distribution with n-1 points first before using Grubbs' test to determine it's an outlier since Grubbs' depends on a normal distribution. If the n-1 distribution might be normal but not assured, is it ok to relax the threshold (alpha value higher than typical 0.05) of the Grubbs' test, accept that the first extreme value is an outlier if the p-value is lower than the relaxed threshold, and then investigate the next extreme value as an outlier using Grubbs' test again for a second iteration?  I'm trying to confirm that this process of testing multiple outliers agrees with his statement when the normality of the distribution is not clear.

Paper Citation: Grubbs, Frank E. “Procedures for Detecting Outlying Observations in Samples.” Technometrics, vol. 11, no. 1, 1969, pp. 1–21. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/1266761. Accessed 7 June 2023.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please give the full paper reference and some context?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Your description of your situation may be a little to vague to be answerable.  Its connection with the Grubb quotation is obscure, too.  Could you edit this post to elaborate on what you're doing and explain what you mean by "relax the threshold"?

Comment: Are you talking about some paper by Grubb***s*** for outlier detection? That echoes his style.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me, and for your feedback!  I definitely can see how it was unclear.  Please let me know if the context makes sense now.  I'm not 100% sure that is the correct paper because I don't have it, it's being quoted to me, but Google gives me that paper when I type his quote into the search bar.

Comment: I think one part of @glen_b's point you haven't addressed yet is that "Grubb" in your title and question body is actually "Grubbs" as written in your citation- an unfortunate problem for statisticians whose surnames end in -s and people assume the "'s" is really "apostrophe s" in things named after them! [Nick Cox has written a handy list of examples where statisticians' names are frequently mangled in this way](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2814/22228)

Comment: Indeed (though at the time I commented, the post didn't include the citation, simply omitting the "s" in both title and first paragraph), so it was important to check whether it was in fact *Grubbs* rather than *Grubb* being asked about (and hence the bold and italic ***s*** in my comment).

Comment: Great feedback!  Some ss have been added.  Now hopefully I can learn some statistics without some mangled dead guy rising from his grave and Poisson'ing me for missing the last 5% of his name.  That s seemed like a removable outlier to me, but clearly, I don't know enough about outlier testing yet to make an accurate judgment.

Comment: This is just another example of "If assumptions aren't satisfied, conclusions don't follow necessarily". Supposedly your data should be normal, except that an outlier may be present as a contaminant. I've never  been tempted to take this scenario seriously, but your situation may differ.  I wouldn't call it OK in any sense unless you think the scenario matches your set-up.  Bad news:  reliable detection of outliers requires subject-matter understanding and careful consideration of alternative views of the data, such as some other brand-name distribution being a better reference distribution.

Comment: Touché.  There is a rabbit hole of questions in one question.   I was naive in thinking of efficiency.  I'll try to split it up into multiple specific questions.  I share your interpretation but had to reach out to see how his statement could have been interpreted differently by those wiser than me.  Thanks